# Causing a Right click event with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, right-click

I'm trying to cause a right click event, from a button press on a visual studio application. What I have is a web control, that when right clicked will pull up some additional controls within it's self. It is on an industrial machine with a touch screen interface. Through the touch screen, we have right click disabled for safety reasons based around the machine. However, on this new web control right click would become a requirement.

I've found a few things such as how to move the mouse cursor, and I definitely know how to manage click events and mouse down events and all that. However I'm not finding any information on triggering a right click event in from a button.

Do you guys have any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for at least my very specific example.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

‘call this in a method somewhere to right click
WebBrowser1.Select() (or wherever you want your mouse)
SendKeys.Send("+{F10}")
```